# Encapsulate results in div tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to turn the following:

```
<div>this is a $test</div>
```

into

```
<div>this is a <div>$test</div></div>
```

currently I have

```
var regexp = new RegExp('$([^\\s]*)','g'),
    html = '<div>this is a $test</div>',
    matched = html.match(regexp)[0]

if (matched){
   html = html.replace(match, '<div>' + match + '</div>')
}
```

which works, but is there a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe you are optimizing too early here.

Comment: `match` only returns an array if it found anything, otherwise it just returns `null`. So be careful there, `html.match(regexp)[0]` will give you a `typeError` if no match was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). As an added bonus, it doesn't fail when there is no match:

```
'<div>this is a $test</div>'.replace(/(\$\w+)/g, '<div>$1</div>')
```